# sending path image from java to python

Tags: java, python-2.7, sockets

I'm trying to send image path from java to python,the path is sent but when i want to open it, it want open

java code

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
      try {
                    // connect to python

                    ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(8080);
                    Socket client = server.accept();
                    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Python27\\Python C:\\Users\\acer\\Desktop\\py\\a.py");

                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
                    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(),true);
                    out.println("C:\Users\acer\Desktop\py\6.bmp");
                    client.close();
                   // System.exit(0);
                } catch (IOException ex) {

                }

    }
```

python code

```
import socket
import random
import os, sys
import numpy
from PIL import Image
HOST = "localhost"
PORT = 8080
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect((HOST, PORT))
data = sock.recv(1024)

d=str(data)
img = d
print "d",d
im = Image.open(data)
#print(im.size, im.format)
row, col = im.size
## some code.............
```

and it give this

```
d 6.bmp
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\acer\Desktop\py\a.py", line 18, in <module>
    im = Image.open(data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2634, in open
    fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('rb') or filename: '6.bmp\r\n'
```

i dont know what is \r\n i just want to send the image path to open the image in python

Comment: Any reason why sockets? Why not as a CLI parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write data like this:

```
   out.println("C:\Users\acer\Desktop\py\6.bmp");
```

you are adding an end-of-line separator.

When you read the data like this:

```
   data = sock.recv(1024)
   d=str(data)
```

you will be including all of the data that you read in the string ... including the line separator.  And that is why the error message says:

```
   IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('rb') or filename: '6.bmp\r\n'
```

See the `\r\n`?  That is the line separator.

You need to trim the line separator from the the filename ...

```
   im = Image.open(data.strip())
```